# tell command in applescript seems to be executed asynchronously

Tags: bash, applescript

I have the following script:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "docker-compose up -d"
    activate
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    do script "until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:1234); do printf '.'; sleep 5; done; exit 0"
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    open location "http://localhost:1234/mypage"
end tell
```

My goal is to open the web page after the service is up and running, but instead it is being opened before. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Terminal’s `do script` command returns immediately. Move the open URL operation to the end of your 2nd shell script; see `man open` for more. Or, if you don’t need the console, perhaps Standard Additions’ `do shell script` would better fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems as though you want this to be non-interactive, you should probably avoid scripting Terminal.app, and just use AppleScript's `do shell script` command. Try this:

```
do shell script "docker-compose up -d; until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:1234)"

tell application "Safari"
    open location "http://localhost:1234/mypage"
end tell
```

`do shell script` should wait until the invoked command is complete before asking Safari to open the page.